# Report users/members in gitlab groups/subgroups/project

Tags: powershell, gitlab, report

I started writing this powershell code to get a report of all my users within the group, subgroups and projects.

But there's one field that doesn't bring me the information, which is the user's last activity on that project.

Why can that be?

Is it possible to further optimize the code even though it takes only 10 minutes?

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param($token)
[Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
$instanceUrl = "https://gitlab.com"

if((Get-Host).Version.Major -le 5){
    write-error "Este script no funciona con powershell 5 o anterior por problemas de encoding"
    exit 1
}

function call-api
{
    param($instanceUrl,
          $endpoint,
          $params,
          $token)
    
    $headers=@{"PRIVATE-TOKEN"=$token}
    $response=@()
    $page = 1
    if($params){ $params = "&$params" }
    do
    {
        $countBeforeInvoke = $response.count
        $response+=Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $headers "$instanceUrl/api/v4/$($endpoint)?private_token=$token&per_page=100&page=$page$params"
        $page++
    }while($response.count -eq $countBeforeInvoke + 100 )
    $response
}

$projects = call-api -instanceUrl $instanceUrl -endpoint "projects" -params "membership=true" -token $token
$projects = $projects |? -Property path_with_namespace -Like "nameOfGroupGitLab/*"



# --------------------------------------------------------------------#

# Obtener la lista de proyectos
$projects = call-api -instanceUrl $instanceUrl -endpoint "projects" -params "membership=true" -token $token
$projects = $projects | ? -Property path_with_namespace -like "smg-code/*"

# Itera a través de la lista de proyectos y obtiene información de los usuarios asociados
foreach ($project in $projects) {
    # Agrega la propiedad "Users" al objeto $project
    $project | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Users" -Value (call-api -instanceUrl $instanceUrl -endpoint "projects/$($project.id)/members" -token $token)
}

# Exporta datos al archivo CSV
$projects | ForEach-Object {
    $project = $_
    $project.Users | ForEach-Object {
        $user = $_
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            ProjectId = $project.id
            ProjectCreated_at = $project.created_at
            ProjectName = $project.name
            ProjectWebUrl = $project.web_url
            UserId = $user.id
            Username = $user.username
            Name = $user.name
            Created_at = $user.created_at
            AccessLevel = $user.access_level
            LastActivityOn = $user.last_activity_at
            CreatedBy = $user.created_by.username
        }
    }
} | Export-Csv -Delimiter ";" -Encoding utf8 reportUser.csv
```

I tried renaming the variables according to the GitLab documentation, within Gitlab I can't find documentation for PowerShell scripts if anyone knows about that information I would like to have it. to be able to expand the possibility of issuing different reports regarding the projects of my company